# On the Windows 10 my app is only ARM even is x86,x64 and ARM are configured & built

Tags: windows-10-universal

I try to publish my W10 universal app on the store.
When it is validated, it appears it is only ARM, instead of ARM/x86/X64.

Here is how look my uploaded packaging in my dashboard. ARM only. Expected ARM/x64/X86.

[image]

When I do [Project]>Store>Create App Package, I check all :
[image]

Then the 3 configurations/architecture are built.

Then only ARM is on the store.

What do I do wrong?
Thanks.